# What is the best equivalent of objective-c NSString * in C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, string, char

I am porting an objective-c application to C++ and am fairly new in either language. In the class I'm handling right now there are quite many fields that are string literals `NSString` or pointers to string `NSString *`. What is the best equivalent of those fields in C++: `std::string`, `std::string *` or `const char *`?

Initially, I thought that `std::string` is more c++-like and `const char *` is more C-like so i should use the former. My colleague says that the latter is preferred because it is faster and lighter and there is no copying involved. However, if I should pass `std::string` as a reference in constructor as `const std::string & param` it would be copied once only.

What would be the best option for me to choose for an equivalent of `NSString *`?

Thanks a lot for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString is an immutable string, so `const std::string` is the right choice. If you use it as reference everywhere, you wouldn't have copies.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer should be to use a `std::string`.  However, depending on your circumstances you might choose `const char *`.  If you use the former correctly, you won't incur too many copying penalties, but you get all sorts of memory safety.